# how to specify the location of Sqlite DB on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask-sqlalchemy

My sqlite DB is on Ubuntu at

```
(venv)jisoo@jisoo:~totalAirQREST/totalAirRunDB$
```

How can I specify the location of the DB in sqlalchemy?

My app.py located in totalAirQREST has the following.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL','sqlite:///airQuality.db')
```

I know I have to change from the sqlite:///airQuality.db, to sqlite:////totalAirRunDB/airQuality.db. But it turns out it is not working. Please help me how to get the app know the location of the sqlite DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try full path

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL','sqlite:////home/jisoo/totalAirQREST/totalAirRunDB/airQuality.db
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please select it as a correct answer.

Comment: I am sorry. Pls. show me how to select it as a correct answer. Do I just press the upward arrow on the left of the answer? Even though I pressed it, nothing changed.